# Named parameter in regex spring-jdbc (postgres)

Tags: sql, spring-jdbc

I am trying to write a parameterized sql query in java code, where the parameter occurs in a regex. So in the following query, the value 11 should be replaced with a parameter.

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE streetnumber '^11[^[:digit:]]*$'
```

The above query returns records with streetnumber: 11A, 11 B, but not 111, which is what I want.

But however I've tried things like:

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE streetnumber ~ '^:streetNumber[^[:digit:]]*$'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE streetnumber ~ ('^' || :streetNumber || '[^[:digit:]]*$')
```

When I run in intellij db console, it returns the expected set, but from java code it returns empty.

Comment: Do you mean a PreparedStatement in java?

Comment: I am Using spring-jdbc, so a prepared statement is created eventually. I define the sql as the strings above. But I actually found that the last select string does work, I had just forgot to remove a % from the value of streetNumber.